# Android, apply a pixelshader on a canvas

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es2

Can an opengl pixelshader be applied on a Canvas?

I want to render a bitmap on a canvas, then apply a pixelshader to get, for example, a blur effect. Is this possible?

I don't want to simulate the blur effect by creating a new bitmap and then blur this from java code because i'd like to be able to re-use the shaders in openGL apps too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no, take a look at this article: http://www.xenomachina.com/2011/05/androids-2d-canvas-rendering-pipeline.html You can use an opengl pixelshader but there are other ways to attain the same.